# Drag and Drop functionality for Canvas in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, canvas, drag-and-drop, custom-controls

i'm working on a project in Silverlight 5, which i have implemented in WPF some months ago. I thought "huh, i will port it in some days..". Wrong :)

To my problem:
I have a listbox and 2-3 canvas-elements on my Window. The listbox contains some string which i want to drag to a Canvas and drop it there as label / textbox / panel or simply a UIElement. Additionaly i want to move the UIElements on the Canvas or move it to another canvas.
In WPF i had no problem to do that.
I'm was searching the last 4 days for a simple / good solution, but i found nothing useable.

Yeah, i know that Silverlight Toolkit has DropTargets (ListBox, TreeView, etc) but is it possible to write a custom targt? A CanvasDropTarget or something like that? Or is it possible to use the PanelDragDropTarget for such a problem?

thanks in advance,
best regards

**Edit:**

I found a thread which seems to be a good start for my solution

- http://forums.silverlight.net/p/194791/452957.aspx

So, i found a solution. I didn't thought thats that simple. I just surrounded a Canvas with a PanelDragDropTarget and it worked.

```
    <toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True" AllowedSourceEffects="All" Height="251" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,27,0,0" Name="panelDragDropTarget1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="302" Grid.Column="1">
           <Canvas Name="canvas1" AllowDrop="True" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="249" Width="308"></Canvas>
    </toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget>
```

and with the events:

```
panelDragDropTarget1.Drop += new Microsoft.Windows.DragEventHandler(panelDragDropTarget1_Drop);        
panelDragDropTarget1.ItemDragStarting += new EventHandler<ItemDragEventArgs>(panelDragDropTarget1_ItemDragStarting);
```

you can handle it.